# Database Retrieval with php

Tags: php, sql, database, join

I'm creating a page where it gets contact details from the forum on registered members. I've hit a little problem trying to retrieve the custom fields. For University and flights a drop down menu is used so that users can select from a specific list. However the forum uses 3 different table to store the data.
This is a small part of the tables

[db mock up http://www.emuas.co.uk/images/db_mock_up.png](http://www.emuas.co.uk/images/db_mock_up.png)

at the moment I get the uni for the uni query and a flight for the flight query, but the result is unrelated to the user_id. Not sure how to change that though.

```
$user = "SELECT * 
  FROM profile_fields_data 
  JOIN users 
    ON profile_fields_data.user_id = users.user_id 
  ORDER BY users.username";

$uni = "SELECT * 
  FROM profile_fields_data
  JOIN users 
    ON profile_fields_data.user_id = users.user_id
  JOIN profile_fields_lang 
    ON profile_fields_data.pf_university = profile_fields_lang.option_id
  WHERE field_id =4
  ORDER BY users.username";

$flight = "SELECT * 
  FROM profile_fields_data
  JOIN users 
    ON profile_fields_data.user_id = users.user_id
  JOIN profile_fields_lang 
    ON profile_fields_data.pf_flight = profile_fields_lang.option_id
  WHERE field_id =3
  ORDER BY users.username";

$userdata = $db->sql_query($user);
$unidata = $db->sql_query($uni);
$flightdata = $db->sql_query($flight);
while($data = $db->sql_fetchrow($userdata))
{
  $datauni = $db->sql_fetchrow($unidata);
  $dataflight = $db->sql_fetchrow($flightdata);
  echo "<tr>
  <td> <a href='http://emuas.co.uk/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=" .    $data['user_id'] . "'>" . $data['username'] . "</a></td>
  <td> <a href='mailto:" . $data['user_email'] . "'>" . $data['user_email'] . "</a>  </td>
  <td>" . $data['pf_contact_number'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $data['user_birthday'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $data['pf_service_number'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $datauni['lang_value'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $dataflight['lang_value'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $data['pf_secondary_duty'] . "</td>
  </tr>";
```

Many thanks

Comment: Hi Byron, so you need a SQL query to select all that information above for one certain user_id? Check out a decent SQL manual (google will help) and look into `JOIN`, try it, and if you need support, post your code - only the SQL though - and ask a question! Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Since you have the users.user_id in both queries could you join them?

Comment: Wouldn't the different where clauses stop me from doing that?

Comment: You can alias the individual queries so the 'where' statements won't argue. You could probably do a UNION query.. that might be easier...

Comment: Think I've found the problem. After reading all the tables the pf_university and pf_flight values seem to be out by +1 on all fields, but the forum is getting the lang_value correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. When the forum got the data for option_id it added 1 to the value. I;ve changed it to take this into account